# how to check if a string is a number without isNaN and with conditions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, string

I want to check if a string is a valid number without using isNaN

because I would like to accept the `,` character that is ignored by isNaN I don't also want to accept negative numbers and the last condition the number should be between 1 and 99.

example :

```
let a = '--5'; // false
let b = '95.5'; // true it can accept . also
let c = '99,8'; // false bigger than 99
let d = '99,'; // false
```

how can I do this. Thank you very much

Comment: You're going to have to explain more clearly what "is a number" means for your application.

Comment: try using regex for matching valid patterns.

Comment: it's a price but it should be between 1 and 99 and I also can accept `,` instead of `.` in my country its more common to use `,` than `.` I want to keep this possibility after that I can manage to make it valid as number while coding

Comment: how about doing `string.replace(",", ".")` first before using parseInt and isNaN?

Comment: Should `99.00` be included or excluded?

Comment: should be included

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const test = '55.'
var res = true;
if(test[0] === '-' || test[test.length-1] === ',' || test[test.length-1] === '.'){
res = false;
}else{
let final = test.replace(/,/g, ".");
if(isNaN(final)){
res = false;
}else{
if(Number(final)>99 ||Number(final) < 1 ) {
res = false;
}}}
console.log(res)
```

note that this is accepting `,56` and `.76` which are valid. but you can add these condition in the first if statement if you want `if(test[0] === '.' || test[0] === ','`

Comment: thats ok I want to accept them

Comment: `I want to check if a string is a valid number without using isNaN`

Comment: though it means not a global isNaN because that does not accept `,`

Answer (score -1):

```js
a = '-5';


 
a = a.replace(/,/g, '.');
//check a is number
if (isNaN(a) || a.startsWith('-') ) {
  console.log('not a number');
}else{
    console.log(' not a number');
      if(a > 0 && a < 100){
         console.log(' a number');
    }
   
    
}
```

Comment: thank your for your help but it says both not a number and a number